# How to cancel the execution of a JavaScript event handler function from the inside of another handler?

Tags: javascript, function, event-handling

When an event handler function gets registered like this:

```
element.onload = function() 
{   
    var something = Selector("identifier", "inline", 1).FadeIn("inline", 1);
    CenterElement(something);
};
```

Is there a way to stop the execution once it starts from the inside of another handler function? Let that handler function look like this:

```
another.onclick = function() 
{
    //Cancel the execution of the above function here
    document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = "Start Slideshow"; 
    this.FadeOut(); 
};
```

`Selector` returns a special wrapper object that isn't relevant for the question itself so the implementation has been omitted.

It's quite known that it's possible to prevent execution of a handler function by assigning `undefined` to the handler variable, but how to stop it if it's already begun executing?

Comment: You can't. JavaScript is single threaded, if a function runs, it runs. Other code can't be executed while a function is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing an important concept here.

In javascript, there is only one thread of execution. While you might think that `onclick` gets called while `onload` is executing, that is plain false.

I don't know what framework you're using, but in jQuery you could do the following:

```
another.onclick = function() 
{
    //Cancel the execution of the above function here
    Selector("identifier", "inline", 1).stop();
    // ...other stuff
};
```

Comment: `.stop` does not simply stop a function. There is a lot more to do in order to make this work and it depends on the function itself whether it's possible to make it "stoppable".

Comment: Oh my god. I didn't know what `stop()` does. Or did I? His problem is with animations which in jQuery can be `stop()`ped... Stop is pretty much useless anywhere else, it's not my problem to tell anyone how it works - there's ample documentation to do it.